# TFTP server for MAC OS X

Tags: mac-osx, tftp

does anyone know any TFTP server for Mac OS X? maybe there is one build-in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's there, you just have to enable it:

Starting the TFTP server on Mac OS X Leopard (sudo needed) (Note this **does not** work with Mac OS X Lion):

- To start the TFTP server, in the terminal window, type: **/sbin/service tftp start**

  - *Your TFTP default folder path will be: **/private/tftpboot***
- To Stop the TFTP server, type: **/sbin/service tftp stop**

To **test** you can tftp to localhost, or you could create a test file.  In terminal, type:

- echo "testing" >/private/tftpboot/testfile
- printf "verbose\ntrace\nget testfile\n" | tftp localhost

---

### TFP Server GUI:

If you're into GUIs, this TFTP server GUI app might work for you: [**http://ww2.unime.it/flr/tftpserver/**](http://ww2.unime.it/flr/tftpserver/)

Answer (score 8):

This solution works on Mac OS X **Lion**.

There already is one:

```
sudo launchctl load -F /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/tftp.plist
sudo launchctl start com.apple.tftpd
```

And, assuming you don't have a typo in either your subject or problem description:

```
sudo launchctl load -F /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ftp.plist
sudo launchctl start com.apple.ftpd
```

Comment: why is the `start com.apple.ftpd` command needed?

Answer (score -2):

Along with +andrew-stannard directions the default target folder for the OSX built in TFTP server is: 
/private/tftpboot/yourfile.bin

Also ensure firewall allows the tftp port (69)

So by naming the file according to the hardware you are recovering specs (I had to recover a group of SNOM IP Phones and neglected 1 letter in the file name which took over an hour to diagnose....grrr)  Once I fixed that letter the phones all pulled the file in no time.

Comment: @Hawken The server is not running by default.