# Setting up an FTP server on Mac OS X Server

Tags: mac-osx-server, ftp

Can anyone direct me to a link that explains how to setup an FTP server on OS X Server? I searched for awhile and didn't find anything very useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by Stuart, the FTP service is built into OS X and the documentation (http://images.apple.com/server/macosx/docs/File_Services_Admin_v10.5.pdf) helps a great deal. For the most basic it's a matter of choosing a file share to share as an FTP folder, setting your permissions and turning on the FTP service in OS X Server.

If you're interested in a more easy to use FTP server I recommend taking a look at [Rumpus](http://www.maxum.com/Rumpus/HomePage.html). At my workplace we opted to go with Rumpus because of the ease to create and lock down accounts to their own folders without adding the users to Open Directory. It also provides a Web based interface for those clients who don't want to use an actual FTP client.

Answer (score 1):

connect to the server using the Server Admin application, click on the Sharing option, and check if the FTP icon indicates that the server is running. See the Mac OS X Server Administrator's Guide for more information on configuring FTP Service on Mac OS X Server 10

http://manuals.info.apple.com/Apple_Support_Area/Manuals/servers/MacosxserverAdmin10.2.3.PDF

Comment: yeah, macs are the easiest on ftp server and web server setup.  i dont even have one and i think so.

Comment: A more current manual can be found at: http://images.apple.com/server/macosx/docs/File_Services_Admin_v10.5.pdf (Chapter 7). 10.2 is just a wee bit old.

Comment: @Chealion: Yeah, I was just thinking the same thing. Couldn't have picked just a *little* more recent version of the admin manual...

Answer (score 0):

This has already been addressed in another question [related specifically to a TFTP server](https://serverfault.com/questions/47014/tftp-server-for-mac-os-x/47019#47019), but is applicable to this question.

Answer (score 0):

I got it up and running using the following manual (updating links because the previous answers have become obsolete):

**Snow Leopard Server File Server Administration:**
http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/FileServerAdmin_v10.6.pdf

**All Apple Server manuals:**
http://support.apple.com/manuals/#serversandenterprisesoftware

And remember to forward ports if you are behind a router.